# How do I best set up a directory of test files in memory instead of disk, in .NET, for testing a file IO class?

Tags: .net, testing, file-io, mstest, ntfs

Suppose I want to test some Windows .NET code that reads, writes, and deletes files based on a directory path.  Suppose that my class to test takes a DirectoryInfo parameter in its constructor.  **What's the best way to set up test files in memory for a .NET automated test, not on an actual disk**?

My first instinct is to set up and tear down a RAM drive, but this doesn't smell right.  Would such an approach be better than using the Path.GetTempPath() directory? Is there a better way to set up a directory of test files?  Or does my class need to take some other abstraction of a collection of files, instead of a DirectoryInfo?

Comment: why not mock a directory info?

Comment: http://systemioabstractions.codeplex.com/

Comment: @DanielA.White, how would you mock DirectoryInfo--write an IMyDirectoryInfo and an adapter to it?  This isn't a pure unit test; I'd like to test the way my class integrates with DirectoryInfo.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how to make the question more specific?  I believe this question can be answered in less than a few paragraphs and only would have one or a few correct answers.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I've done this in the past by creating a facade interface over the directory and file actions, that underneath are either implemented by `System.IO` or by a test implementation that uses dictionaries to store files. The only other thing I can think of is some sort of hijacking of methods, perhaps using [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Adam--a very good answer;  I think it shows the question is not too broad.

Comment: @DanielAWhite, could you please elaborate on why you closed this question?  I believe this question can be answered in less than a few paragraphs and only would have one or a few correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Adam Houldsworth:

I've done this in the past by creating a facade interface over the directory and file actions, that underneath are either implemented by System.IO or by a test implementation that uses dictionaries to store files. The only other thing I can think of is some sort of hijacking of methods, perhaps using [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).